# Catching specific exception from riak-java-client from Clojure

Tags: java, exception, clojure, riak

I use the following Clojure code to wrap `.ping` from the [riak-java-client](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client). But I don't like being this blunt with exception catching:

```
(ns myapp.riak
  (:import [com.basho.riak.client IRiakClient]))

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn alive?
  "Is Riak client alive? Returns true or false, unlike `.ping`."
  [^IRiakClient client]
  (try
    (.ping client) true
    (catch Exception e false)))
```

I tried catching these:

- `com.basho.riak.client.RiakException`
- `java.net.ConnectException`
- `java.io.IOException`

But none of these (alone or in combination) worked.

What am I doing wrong?

3:56 pm EDT update: I'm using `RiakFactory/httpClient`, in case it matters.

4:13 pm EDT update: One interesting aspect is the debugging process. While debugging, `ConnectException` showed up in the REPL. But `RiakIORuntimeException` -- part of a solution below -- did not show up. I wonder why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ping throws RiakException - https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/basho/riak/client/DefaultRiakClient.java#L210

Next function works for me. I don't have riak installed and it returns **false**

```
(ns riak.core
  (:import [com.basho.riak.client IRiakClient RiakFactory RiakException]
           [com.basho.riak.client.http.response RiakIORuntimeException]))

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
;; (def client (RiakFactory/pbcClient))
(def client (RiakFactory/httpClient))

(defn alive?
  "Is Riak client alive? Returns true or false, unlike `.ping`."
  [^IRiakClient client]
  (try
    (.ping client)
    true
    (catch RiakException e false)
    (catch RiakIORuntimeException e false)))
```

REPL:

```
riak.core> (alive? client)
false
```

**UPDATE:** Added RiakIORuntimeException case for httpClient